# Can an .ICO file be used as an image in a button?

Tags: .net, winforms, image, button, ico

Can an `.ICO` file be used as an image for a `Winforms` button?

Comment: Try it. What issues have you had with trying?

Comment: I saw that the expected file types were all images and did not include `ICO`.

Comment: Fine, but what's stopping you from using just about any image editor to convert the `ICO` to a `BMP`, `PNG` or `GIF`?

Comment: Can you recommend an image editor?  None of the ones installed with Windows can do it.

Comment: Paint.NET is free. GIMP as well.

Comment: Visual Studio has an image editor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.

Browse on the Image property. Check Local Resource. Click Import. Change filter to show All Files. Select your .ico file.

Not sure which image it will choose from your .ico though.

Comment: When I do this it says `"Not a valid resource type"`.

Comment: Okay, this was in 2010, I guess it might not work in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Icon's ToBitmap method to convert an Icon to an Image programmatically.